# How to handoff Dialogflow Agent to Human in Google Assistant?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a Dialogflow agent integrated with Google Assistant. I want to integrate agent to human hand off feature into my Google Assistant action using Dialogflow.

Comment: Does it work with Google Assistant?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible, the Dialogflow session is the only connection you have to your user and it is only kept alive if your webhook responds within the timeout limit. You could technically hook into the fulfillment code and prompt a human to enter the live response, but they would have to do that before the request times out, i.e. within a few seconds.

Comment: Yes.. I know about it. But I thought  If somebody can help.